# Problems with bluetooth pand on rooted android 2.3.1 device

Tags: bluetooth-tethering

I have a tablet Aishuo A820, rooted. I tried to connecto to my GSM using PAN network with following commands:

```
pand --connect <device address>
ifconfig bnep0 up
```

and it worked. Then I had to stop testing and later I tried the same commands but it never works. `logcat` shows:

```
E/pand    ( 3255): Connect to <device address> failed. Connection timed out(110)
```

I can't understand what's different this time. I used sshDroid to connect over wifi both times. I tried under some consoles with wifi off - same result.

I tried to re-pair devices. Then I start `pand` again with `--connect`. The phone asks to give access. I answer allow and again timeout. I also tried "always allow" so the phone don't have to ask for permission. Nothing works! How did it work the first time?

Answer (score 1):

I can't specifically answer your question, however, what I've found BT paring my Nexus 7 (JB 4.2) to my (rooted) Motorola Defy phone (Froyo 2.2.2), using standard setup panels, is similar. That is, it works the first time. On subsequent attempts, I see a 'connecting..' message then the BT Paring/Connection panel quickly returns to 'waiting for user input' with no connection.

In order to 'fix' it I have to reboot the Motorola (phone).